# at a specific startindex check for space if any is found remove that specific space the text after it and add "..."

Tags: c#, string, replace, substring

I have a bunch of title texts that get generated they all have different `.Length` but at a specific startindex of the string I want to find the closest space and then remove the text after it and also the space, and then add "...".

The most important part is that it shouldnt extend 49 length

Example:

```
"What can UK learn from Spanish high speed rail when its crap"
```

I want to make sure that it becomes:

```
"What can UK learn from Spanish high speed rail..."
```

So far I created

```
if (item.title.Length >= 49)
{
    var trim = item.title.Substring(' ', 49) + "...";
}
```

But this one can do following thing:

```
"What can UK learn from Spanish high speed rail it..."
```

which is wrong.

Any kind of help is appreciated or any kind of tips on how to achieve this.

Comment: when you say closest space, is it closest space to the magic 49 number?

Comment: yes exacly the string should never be over 49 length thats why its importan that it takes the closest space before 49 length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should trim at the last space, it also handles the case that there is no space in the allowed part:

```
public static string TrimLength(string text, int maxLength)
{
    if (text.Length > maxLength)
    {
        maxLength -= "...".Length;
        maxLength = text.Length < maxLength ? text.Length : maxLength;
        bool isLastSpace = text[maxLength] == ' ';
        string part = text.Substring(0, maxLength);
        if (isLastSpace)
            return part + "...";
        int lastSpaceIndexBeforeMax = part.LastIndexOf(' ');
        if (lastSpaceIndexBeforeMax == -1)
            return part + "...";
        else
            return text.Substring(0, lastSpaceIndexBeforeMax) + "...";
    }
    else
        return text;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/zqFFIX)

> What can UK learn from Spanish high speed rail...

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. This method probably breaks down if you have really huge words, but it should get you started.

```
public static string Ellipsify(string source, int preferredWidth)
{
    string[] words = source.Split(' '); //split the sentence into words, separated by spaces
    int readLength = 0;
    int stopAtIndex = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++) {
        readLength += words[i].Length; //add the current word's length
        if(readLength >= preferredWidth) { //we've seen enough characters that go over the preferredWidth
            stopAtIndex = i;
            break;
        }
        readLength++; //count the space
    }
    string output = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < stopAtIndex; i++)
    {
        output += words[i] + " ";
    }
    return output.TrimEnd() + "..."; //add the ellipses
}
```